# Is there a way to connect 2 browsers without a server? Maybe with Websockets?

Tags: html, tcp, websocket

I'm looking for a way to connect 1 browser to another without having to incur the network delay of having a server in between.

It doesn't look like HTML5 WebSockets will work because I couldn't find a way to listen for connections in Javascript, only establish a connection.

Does anyone know how to do this? (Connect 2 browsers directly? Like via the 2 computers' IP's directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is just not doable with JavaScript.

You'll need a client written in a language that has access to the OS' networking API.

Comment: Flash's Cirrus looks like it could be a way, but doesn't seem to be out of beta yet. Ended up dealing with the server in the middle and that was fast enough.

Answer (score 9):

It is funny how things change rapidly with JavaScript, and the fact that the accepted answer (from 2010) says it is not possible :-)

In 2013 yes there is a way to have direct browser to browser communication: [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/). It is part of HTML5, and it is being actively developed. It is already available, for example, in Chrome stable releases and in nightly builds of Firefox.

A WebRTC browser provides JavaScript interfaces for:

- MediaStreams: access to the host hardware: camera, mic, speaker.
- ICE for NAT traversal.
- PeerConnection: direct browser-to-browser communication for audio/video streaming.
- DataChannel: direct browser-to-browser communication for custom data.

See this [blog post](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/) for an introduction (a bit outdated, a lot more has been implemented already), this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=E8C8ouiXHHk) for a very good overview, the W3C WebRTC [JavaScript API](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html) and the associated RFCs and Internet Drafts for the network protocols.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a perfect solution, but it is a way for you to broadcast directly from a client to all the other clients on the channel. NB: it uses Pusher, which is a Freemium service that I have found to be awesome and reliable. If they have figured out a way to do it, then there must be a way. Their source code is also available on GitHub.

http://pusher.com/docs/client_events

From their site:

> Not all traffic needs to go via your conventional webserver when using Pusher. Some trivial actions which don't need persistence can go directly via the socket to all the other clients connected to the channel.

Hope that helps.